# Can I deploy .Net Application to IIS from Linux?

Tags: docker, jenkins, iis, deployment

I have an IIS (be configured) on the Windows server. 
I have a Jenkins system (be deployed on Linux machine) to build .Net code (on the Docker container). 
And then I would like to deploy the Artifact was built on the previous stage to IIS on the Windows server.

So, How I can deploy to IIS on the Windows server?

Comment: .Net core is easier to deploy .Net application on Linux

Comment: @MetallimaX Yes. I know this. But I would like to deploy to IIS. :(

Comment: What kind of artifacts do you deploy? ASP.NET Core projects only need the results of `dotnet publish` to be xcopy-ed, so you can use UNC path or FTP.

Comment: @LexLi This is the results of  `dotnet publish`, I just need copy this folder to deploy server. I will try UNC path or FTP.

Comment: I think we can transfer the files of the .Net Application release version from Linux to windows, and then we can add a site directly in IIS. The physical path of the site is the file of the .Net Application release version transferred from Linux.

Comment: @DingPeng, Thanks for your information. I think so.